# merging dicts not working as expected python 3.5

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.5

This is Python 3.5 environment, I think the code is self explanatory, here it is, I am expecting both functions to work, but only one is correct.

TLDR:
Assigning `out = {**out, **answer}` makes `out` variable containing right keys, but they are lost during the next 2 steps; while assigning `c = {**c,**a}` works perfectly in test function, and new keys are not lost.

Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

```
def flatify_works(d, out, fhook=None):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if not isinstance(v, dict) and not isinstance(v, list):
            out[k] = v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            flatify_works(v, out, fhook)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            if fhook is None:
                raise AssertionError("an array with more than 1 elment found.")
            answer = fhook(k, v)
            for k, v in answer.items():
                out[k] = v


def flatify_doesnt_work(d, out, fhook=None):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if not isinstance(v, dict) and not isinstance(v, list):
            out[k] = v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            flatify_doesnt_work(v, out, fhook)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            if fhook is None:
                raise AssertionError("an array with more than 1 elment found.")
            answer = fhook(k, v)
            out = {**out, **answer}  # put a breakpoint here, and go 2 steps further


def hook(k, v):
    l = [d["c"] for d in v]
    return {"c": sum(l), "d": "blabla"}


def test_merge_dicts():
    a = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
    c = {"c": 3}
    c = {**c, **a}  # merging works perfectly here
    print(c)
    assert "a" in c and "b" in c and "c" in c  # ok


def test_nested_works():
    out = {}
    flatify_works({"a": 1, "b": [{"c": 0.6, "d": 4}, {"c": 0.4, "d": 4}]}, out, hook)
    print("working exemple: {}".format(str(out)))


def test_nested_doesnt_work():
    out = {}
    flatify_doesnt_work({"a": 1, "b": [{"c": 0.6, "d": 4}, {"c": 0.4, "d": 4}]}, out, hook)
    print("not working exemple: {}".format(str(out)))


def main():
    test_merge_dicts()  # ok
    test_nested_works() # ok
    test_nested_doesnt_work() # why out = {**out, **answer} is not working as expected?


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is that much code really needed to demonstrate this issue?

Comment: I dont know, it is better more than not enough?

Comment: Surely, you can minimize this. Based on the title of your question, I would expect your example to be two dictionaries, the code responsible for that exact logic, the output showing how it is broken, and what it should look like.

Comment: Reducing your code to the smallest necessary to duplicate the problem will 1) greatly improve answers 2) improve your understanding of the problem 3) might help you figure out the problem on your own

Comment: I made it explicit, just copy past in your IDE, it will work

Comment: But then you're making everyone else do the work of figuring out what your code does, rather than doing that yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the difference is that in the second function, you reassign the `out` variable, after which it is detached from the dict that you pass into the function:

```
out = {**out, **answer} # out is now a different object
```

Since the function is recursive, the subsequent modifications do not affect the original dict.

In the first function, though, you only do item assignment, which modifies the dict in place, as expected:

```
out[k] = v
```

Comment: I thought it is not possible to create 2 different objects with the same neme, in the same scope?

Comment: @DenisGantsev The name refers to one object at any given time. The assignment statement is when the name is bound to a different object.

Comment: hum, this makes sens!